# Unparseable date: ",Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01 (at ofest 0) - Android

Tags: java, android

I have a date which is like so

```
Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01
```

And I want to convert this into the format:

```
05/09/2014
```

I am using the following code to do so:

```
pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 23);    
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

But, it bringing back the above error messages...I do not know why.

If someone could give me some help, that would be great...thanks!

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/nYTBV3

Comment: Is the comma and space `, ` in the beginning a part of your input you're trying to parse?

Comment: `pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 23);` should be `pubDateFormat = pubDate.substring(0, 22);` (the string is only 22 characters long), but I couldn't make my ideone.com example fail by adding an extra character at the end, so...

Comment: @laalto: I think that's probably the answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Yes, it should be displayed with the ,. And also, Hmmm, when I reduce it to 22, it chops off the last char of the time?

Comment: @Callum: Surely it's fairly clear? Your format is `EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm`, but what you're trying to parse starts with `", "`. So it doesn't match. You'll have to remove the `", "` from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
Unparseable date: ", Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01
```

There's an extra comma and space `,` at the beginning of your input that are not a part of the format pattern you're using. Either remove the extra chars from the input, or update your format pattern to expect a literal comma and space there.

Comment: Additionally, by applying `.substring(0, 23)` to it, the OP is trying to parse `", Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:0"`.

Comment: The comma is not there, I added that by mistake sorry.

Comment: @Callum: Is the space there? If so, it will make the string unparseable by your format.

Comment: @Callum Consider updating the question with the exact exception you're getting.

Comment: @Callum: You said the comma isn't there, then edited your question title to remove the **space** and leave the comma. When asking for help with parsing a data format, being precise about what you're parsing is pretty much Step 1. Otherwise, you're just wasting peoples' time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, the problem is **extra space** before **" Fri"** , See `" Fri"`, that is why not parsing, not because of comma

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try {
            //remove the space in front of string, basically trim it
            String pubDateFormat = "Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:01";
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = dateFormatter.parse(pubDateFormat);
            dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```